# Security exception while customizing google setupwizard in Oreo

Tags: android, android-securityexception, setup-wizard

Custom setupwizard + google setupwizard -> homescreen

- Referred GmsSampleIntegration
- Written a separate custom setup wizard application(apk)
- Custom setupwizard is launching successfully
- While launching google setupwizard after custom setupwizard facing below:
  Unable to resume activity {com.google.android.setupwizard/com.google.android.setupwizard.network.NetworkActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: NetworkScoreService: Neither user 10037 nor current process has android.permission.REQUEST_NETWORK_SCORES.

Observation :

REQUEST_NETWORK_SCORES is a signature level permission

- Tried below mentioned options :

  - Placed custom setupwizard as priv-app
  - Used android.uid.system in manifestfile
  - Declared REQUEST_NETWORK_SCORES in manifest
  - category SETUP_WIZARD in manifest
  - action DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of wizard script it was pointing to google package, I changed to custom setupwizard package. No security exception found after that.

Comment: Hello, Can you mention what file you have changed the custom setupwizard? did you modify the vendor/google/ mk files?